# Need to concatenate multiple array values using BooleanBuilder

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

Trying to concatenate array values that look like pseudo code:
`SELECT * FROM (fiscalYear = 2017 OR fiscalYear = 2018)`
`AND (accountingPeriod = 2017 OR accountingPeriod = 2018)`

Current output is: 
`SELECT * FROM fiscalYear = 2017 OR fiscalYear = 2018`

I have tried using multiple connections of BooleanBuilder, and also creating one large loop around all of the returns. Nothing has worked.

```
@Service
public class FilterService {

    @Autowired
    SpendRepository spendRepository;

    public Iterable<Spend> filterSpendingByAll(Integer[] fiscalYear, Integer[] accountingPeriod, String[] department, String[] apCategory,
                                               String[] jurisdiction, String[] functionName, String[] vendorId) {

        QSpend spend = QSpend.spend;

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < fiscalYear.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.fiscalYear.eq(fiscalYear[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < accountingPeriod.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.accountingPeriod.eq(accountingPeriod[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < department.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.department.like("%" + department[i] + "%"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < apCategory.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.apCategory.like("%" + apCategory[i] + "%"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < jurisdiction.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.jurisdiction.like("%" + jurisdiction[i] + "%"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < functionName.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.functionName.like("%" + functionName[i] + "%"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vendorId.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.vendorId.like("%" + vendorId[i] + "%"));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < vendorId.length; i++){
            builder.or(spend.vendorId.eq(vendorId[i]));
        }

        return this.spendRepository.findAll(builder);


    }
}
```

Actual result is:
`SELECT * FROM fiscalYear = 2017 OR fiscalYear = 2018`

Expected result is: 
`SELECT * FROM (fiscalYear = 2017 OR fiscalYear = 2018)`
`AND (accountingPeriod = 2017 OR accountingPeriod = 2018)`

Comment: Not what you asked, but be very careful with order of operations.  In SQL, AND is evaluated before OR, so you'll probably need parentheses to achieve what you want.  I would write your example query as `SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE fiscalYear IN (2017, 2018) AND accountingPeriod in (2017, 2018)`

Comment: uses parentheses `SELECT * FROM (fiscalYear = 2017 OR fiscalYear = 2018) AND (accountingPeriod = 2017 OR accountingPeriod = 2018)`